# Configuring Flycheck to work with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, emacs, flycheck

I am having significant trouble configuring flycheck for C++11. Right now, flycheck is flagging things like `std::to_string()`. The checker I am using is just g++. What can I add in the .emacs file such that flycheck will assume C++11 by default?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Flycheck provides the option `flycheck-gcc-language-standard` for this purpose.  You should not set it globally, because that will break checking of C files, but you can set it from `c++-mode-hook` with the following code in your init file:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (setq flycheck-gcc-language-standard "c++11")))
```

However, I would recommend against this.  Instead, use [Directory Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) to configure the language standard per project.

Open the root directory of your project in Dired with `C-x d`, and then type `M-x add-dir-local-variable RET c++-mode RET flycheck-gcc-language-standard RET "c++11"`.   This will create a `.dir-locals.el` file in the root directory of your project.  Emacs reads this file whenever you visit a file from this directory or any subdirectory, and sets variables according to the rules in this file.  Specifically, Emacs will now set the language standard for Flycheck syntax checking to C++ 11 for all C++ files in your project.

Comment: I tried that with directory variables and in the C++ buffer, the variable shows as *c++11*. But I still got warning as *auto type specifier is a C++11 extension*.

Comment: @Enzo Chi, Works for me, probably you need to delete the file buffer and reopen the file.

Comment: Just in case it does not work for some people: it seems that flycheck will use clang before gcc if the former is installed. In that case the variable is flycheck-clang-language-standard.

Comment: I have nested projectile directories How to set this function recursively for all directory under tree ?

Comment: c++-mode is not an option,  but I have c-c++/[]-cc-mode, and in the brackets the options {init, init-cmake, pre-init, post-init-cc, ...} how can I set up the std=c++11?

Comment: If setting *language standard* doesn't work for you, you can always set compiler flags directly: `(setq flycheck-clang-args "-std=c++11")`

Answer (score 11):

Very good answers already. I just want to add, that if you use `clang` instead, then the variable needed to be modified is `flycheck-clang-language-standard`.

Comment: or add one line "-std=c++11" in the .clang_complete file located at the root directory of your project.